# R: Understanding variable selection in MICE for imputing data

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-mice

EDIT: This is not a course with a live instructor and I cannot ask him directly in any way. If it were, I wouldn't be wasting your time here.

I am taking an R class that is dealing with the basics of machine learning. We are working with the Vanderbilt Titanic dataset available [HERE](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/DataSets/titanic3.csv/). The goal is the use the R `mice` package to imput missing `age` values. I've already split my data into train and test samples, and `str(training)` outputs:

```
'data.frame':   917 obs. of  14 variables:
 $ pclass   : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ survived : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ name     : chr  "Allen, Miss. Elisabeth Walton" "Allison, Master. Hudson Trevor" "Allison, Miss. Helen Loraine" "Allison, Mrs. Hudson J C (Bessie Waldo Daniels)" ...
 $ sex      : Factor w/ 2 levels "female","male": 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ age      : num  29 0.92 2 25 48 63 71 18 24 26 ...
 $ sibsp    : int  0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ parch    : int  0 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ticket   : chr  "24160" "113781" "113781" "113781" ...
 $ fare     : num  211.3 151.6 151.6 151.6 26.6 ...
 $ cabin    : chr  "B5" "C22 C26" "C22 C26" "C22 C26" ...
 $ embarked : Factor w/ 4 levels "","C","Q","S": 4 4 4 4 4 4 2 2 2 4 ...
 $ boat     : chr  "2" "11" "" "" ...
 $ body     : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA 22 NA NA NA ...
 $ home.dest: chr  "St Louis, MO" "Montreal, PQ / Chesterville, ON" "Montreal, PQ / Chesterville, ON" "Montreal, PQ / Chesterville, ON" ...
```

The instructor then goes on to write:

```
factor_vars <- c('pclass', 'sex', 'embarked', 'survived')

training[factor_vars] <- lapply(training[factor_vars], function(x) as.factor(x))

impute_variables <- c('pclass', 'sex', 'age', 'sibsp', 'parch', 'fare', 'embarked')
mice_model <- mice(training[,impute_variables], method='rf')
mice_output <- complete(mice_model)
mice_output
```

I understand the `factor_vars` piece - these variables are labelled as factors in the structure output. What I don't understand is how the `impute_variables` were chosen or what they mean exactly. Are they arbitrarily chosen, perhaps on the basis that the instructor believed things like `'pclass'` (which is the indicator for steerage, coach, or first class) may help predict age (with older people being able to afford first class perhaps) while things like `'cabin'` would have no relevance?

Furthermore, in the line `mice_model <- mice(training[,impute_variables], method='rf')`, which portion of the function is declaring that we want to be imputing the age of the passengers?

Comment: These sound like questions to ask your instructor....

Comment: It is not a live course, that is not an option. I would not have asked the question otherwise

Comment: Did you at least start by looking at the help page for the `?complete` function? Or maybe checkout the resources vignette from the `mice` package for help in understanding how the package works: `vignette("resources", "mice")`

Comment: Yes - the help page says that complete "exports" the results which I'm a bit unclear on. The vignettes are a bit over my head, I started learning R less than a week ago.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.  It is a question about why the tutor sleceted certain parameters to impute.  Can only be answered by that instructor

Comment: I disagree. I don't actually care about the instructor's logic, just the functional reason for choosing any variable over another for imputation